# Why does the Google toolbar show no Pagerank after a 301 redirect?

Tags: google, 301-redirect, pagerank

As we all know, Google treats sub-domains as completely separate domains so we have to fight for both, to get ranked in search results.

One of my client's websites had `example.com` and `blog.example.com`. So to keep all the stuff in one place, we redirected `blog.example.com` to `example.com/blog/`

But in this case, we lost our Pagerank and are still wondering where we went wrong.  Maybe it just takes more time to show up. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4):

The Pagerank won't show up as transferred until the next Pagerank update takes place.  The last one was about 2 weeks ago so it will show up in about 10 weeks.

This is the public Pagerank, the Pagerank Google actually uses is updated constantly but they don't display it to the public.  They only show a abbreviated version once every 3 months.